# Backbone: get model from collection

Tags: backbone.js

Im playing around with Backbone and are experiencing something I don't quite understand:

1) I have created some mock data in "data/applications.js"

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "title": "Title #1",
    "image": "some/path1"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "title": "Title #2",
    "image": "some/path2"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "title": "Title #3",
    "image": "some/path4"
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "title": "Title #4",
    "image": "some/path4"
  }
]
```

2) Im trying to retrieve a single "application" in a collection

```
ApplicationModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});

ApplicationCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: "data/applications.json",
  model: ApplicationModel
});

var applications = new ApplicationCollection();
applications.fetch();
var application = applications.get(applicationId); // I get this from route

console.log(applicationId); // returns 2
console.log(applications); // returns the collection with 4 models
console.log(application); // returns undefined
```

I have a feeling Im missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you fetch data with Backbone, it is done asynchronously, which means that your script continues to be executed while it is fetching. To retrieve your application, you have to wait for the fetch to end like that :

```
applications.fetch({success: function() {
        console.log(applications.get(applicationId));
}});
```